# How to power 460W with a battery for 15 minutes?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging

I need to support a 460W (max) power supply up and running for 15 mins using a battery. I am looking for suggestions on what kind of battery packs can I use?

Comment: What is the input voltage required by the power supply?

Comment: Do you need to keep the supply running for five minutes _while it is supplying 460W_, or will it be supplying less?  Do you have the specifications for the power drawn by the power supply when it is supplying 460W?

Comment: What is the environment the battery will be in: indoors, outdoors, temperature range, etc..

Comment: Have you looked at the specifications of commercial UPS units? You’ll need peak and average actual power consumption.

Comment: Does the charger need to be built into your system, or can the battery be charged offline?

Comment: Product recomendations are not valid for this site.  And you have not provided enough info to answer the question or addressed the comments.

Comment: You need 115 watt hours of batteries (max).

Comment: He didn't ask *what* battery. He asked what kind of battery. That's not a shopping question.

Comment: We gave the OP less than 7 hours to answer our questions and closed the post. Is that how we want to do things?

Comment: (@mkeith The harsh word *close* doesn't mean *forget this question*, just *don't answer until significantly improved*.)

Comment: @mkeith Your concern about voltage is crucial to an answer. Is it 460W continuously?  We are engineers and the details are important.  Someone could create a great quality answer to  the wrong question.

Comment: @mkeith - I agree this is (currently) not a shopping question. It asks for help deciding on a *kind* of battery, not a specific model which could be out-of-stock etc. I interpret that as asking about Li-ion vs. SLA vs. NiMH etc and mentioning "shopping question" has unfortunately muddied things here. However, the question *is* missing important details / context / constraints. IMHO the "closed" state is poorly named. As you remember, it used to be called being put "on hold", which I think better explained that state. If the OP adds missing details, this should be reopened.

Comment: Neil Dey - Please see [here](/help/closed-questions) about closed question & [edit] your question to add details requested in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I agree. I just though allowing a little more time before closing would be nice. I think a lot of people might be deterred if their question is closed. Rather than fix it up they will abandon it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with basically any type of battery. A large Lithium Ion pack can do that easily. For example lets say **10Ah 6S, 10C**. That's a capacity of 100A at ~22V, so **2200W** max. The battery stores 10Ah * 22V = **220Wh** of energy. You need 460W*0.25h = **115Wh**. So you would half drain the pack.

You're in luck that this falls right into the relm of EV and larger drone batteries, so it should be easy to find one that suits you.

Comment: Yes, an electric lawn mower battery is about the right capacity. Some, e.g. Ryobi, have 3rd party DIY adapters available. But, building a charger is not trivial, you should charge off-line with a purchased charger.

Comment: Agreed. He should buy a battery *and* a charger. I personally prefer the drone packs. They don't have a BMS, so they require a balance charger, but that also means you can store them for years (at storage charge), without them dying.